# Waterfall plots and charts (and R)

Tags: r, data-visualization

First of all, looks like there are two kind of "waterfall" data visualization:
Waterfall charts (mostly used in finance) like this:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart
And waterfall plots (mostly used in science) like these:
http://scigra.ph/post/21332335998/scigraph-another-graphic-design-blog

I am trying to make a second kind (waterfall PLOT) in something like R. But when I try googling it - mostly the first kind (waterfall CHART) comes out. Any suggestions on how to make similar plots in R (assume I have x, y, z)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a ready-made function for the plot you're after, but cooking your own script in R is not that complicated. Here's an example.

```
# Simulate the data (from normal distribution)
d<-rnorm(1000)
# Calculate the density of the data
xd<-density(d)$x
yd<-density(d)$y
# Specify how many curves to plot
no.of.curves<-51

# Open a new plot window
x11(6, 8)
# Set background to black
par(bg=1)
# The the initial plot
plot(x=xd, y=yd+(no.of.curves-1)/10, ylim=c(0,no.of.curves/10+max(yd)), col="grey50", type="l", lwd=2)
# Color the curve with black
polygon(xd, yd+(no.of.curves-1)/10-0.02, col="black", border=NA)
# Add more urves to the plot
for(i in 1:no.of.curves) {
   lines(x=xd, y=yd+(no.of.curves-i)/10, ylim=c(0,no.of.curves/10+max(yd)), col="grey50", type="l", lwd=2)
   polygon(xd, yd+(no.of.curves-i)/10-0.02, col="black", border=NA)
}
```

This should create something conceptually similar, but not exactly the same plot:

[image]
If this is what you're looking for, the script above can be turned into a function that would produce the plot for any data set. Can you possibly provide some example data set that you would like to plot?

For the data in the comment, the following code will produce filled areas instead of lines, and the colors have been reversed:

```
d<-structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
    y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), z = c(5.47, 
    3.36, 2.99, 3.04, 3.73, 3.25, 3.04, 2.19, 1.6, 2.63, 3.49, 
    2.48, 2.7, 1.6, 2.7, 3.33, 1.94, 2.39, 2.89, 2.94, 4.35, 
    3.21, 3.4, 3.36, 4.74)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))

yvals<-rev(unique(d$y))
plot(x=0, y=0, ylim=c(min(d$y), max(d$y)+max(d$z)), xlim=c(min(d$x), max(d$x)), type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="") 
 for(i in 1:length(yvals)) {
   a<-d[d$y==yvals[i],]
   polygon(x=a$x, y=a$z+i, border="grey75", col="black")
}
```

For these data there is no constant base line, and the polygons (colored areas) look a bit weird.

Comment: That is a very detailed answer, thank you very much! However, the way you plot it, you only have x and y. I want to plot x, y, and z and all lines will be different. For example, data set like this: [x y z]1 1 5.47
1 2 3.36
1 3 2.99
1 4 3.04
1 5 3.73
2 1 3.25
2 2 3.04
2 3 2.19
2 4 1.60
2 5 2.63
3 1 3.49
3 2 2.48
3 3 2.70
3 4 1.60
3 5 2.70
4 1 3.33
4 2 1.94
4 3 2.39
4 4 2.89
4 5 2.94
5 1 4.35
5 2 3.21
5 3 3.40
5 4 3.36
5 5 4.74

Comment: In my answer, there are actually x, y, and z variables. Z is the height of the curve, X is the horizontal axis of the plot, and Y is the i in the for loop. The data was shaped as a matrix of X*Y and Z were the values in the matrix. I edited the answer to fit the shape of the dat you posted.